# Setup for more than 4 players in Dominion?

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity, dominion-alchemy, game-setup

We have the base *Dominion* set along with the **Alchemy** and **Prosperity** expansions. The rules cover 2-4 players, but elsewhere it implies that up to 6 players are allowed with expansions. Nowhere we could find does it explain if 5 or 6 players have a different setup or end game conditions.

Do you need a different setup for 5 - 6 players in Dominion? I get the impression that adding the **Colony** and **Platinum** is required, but not sure if the starting cards or end conditions change. Or is it a different expansion that allows for 5 - 6 players?

I am open to "official rules" and "recommended rules."

Comment: Don't forget that the number of Curses in play should be (n-1) * 10, where n is the number of players.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The official rules for 5-6 players in Dominion is outlined in the [Dominion: Intrigue](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_306_gameRules.pdf) rulebook, as it requires the extra treasure and Province cards included with that expansion.

> To set up for 5 or 6 players, combine the Treasure cards from Dominion and Dominion: Intrigue. Use 15 Provinces in the Supply for a 5-player game and 18 Provinces in the Supply for a 6-player game. All other Victory card piles (Estates, Duchies, and Victory Kingdom cards) remain at 12 cards per pile. Use 40 Curse cards for a 5-player game and 50 Curse cards for a 6-player game.
>
> In a 5 or 6 player game, the game ends at the end of any player’s turn when one of two conditions is met: the Supply pile of Province cards is empty OR any 4 Supply piles are empty.

I would recommend using these rules with proxy cards for the extra treasures, Provinces and Curses if you don't have the Intrigue expansion.

Comment: @TheChaz & Ghoppe: Thanks to both of you for the speedy answers. I suspected it was Intrigue that added 5-6 players. I'll look at picking that one up or making some proxies. So just need more Province and Curse cards? No more Gold?

Comment: @JimMcKeeth The rules say combine the Treasure cards. So, I suppose that means technically you'd double the Copper, Silver, and Gold.

Comment: IMO it works better if you ALSO add extra Duchy cards (match the number of provinces) AND add an extra kingdom pile per player over 4.

Comment: @ChrisDodd do you also modify the game-end conditions (e.g. 4 piles run out for 5 players?)

Comment: Should there also be 15/18 colonies in a 5/6 player colony game?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, the number of Colonies should equal the number of Provinces.

Comment: So it requires Intrigue 1st edition as 2nd does not have the additional base cards.

Comment: I just got the second edition big box: the intrigue rules do not have that section above (assumedly because as Bence says they don't specifically include extra base cards) however the big box DOES include extra base cards (says so on the box) however it doesn't seem to be written anywhere how to use them...

Answer (score 3):

Neither Colony nor Platinum are required for 5-6 player. (Neither of them are in Intrigue, either.)

From the Intrigue Rules PDF:

> The following are rules for a single game accommodating 5 or 6 players. Please note
>   that there will be increased downtime with 5 or 6 players, so this is not recommended
>   for new players.
>
> To set up for 5 or 6 players, combine the Treasure cards from Dominion and Dominion:
>   Intrigue. Use 15 Provinces in the Supply for a 5-player game and 18 Provinces in the
>   Supply for a 6-player game. All other Victory card piles (Estates, Duchies, and Victory
>   Kingdom cards) remain at 12 cards per pile. Use 40 Curse cards for a 5-player game and
>   50 Curse cards for a 6-player game.
>
> In a 5 or 6 player game, the game ends at the end of any player’s turn when one of two
>   conditions is met: the Supply pile of Province cards is empty OR any 4 Supply piles are
>   empty

The designer's advice for 7-8 players is to run two separate tables of 3-4p

The full intrigue rules are available at
http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/45425/dominion-intrigue-rules-english-pdf